# How to avoid adding new line after header when formatting markdown files with Prettier

Tags: markdown, prettier, formatter

Currently when I save the file it will automatically format the file by adding new line between the header and paragraph. Is there a way to turn off that option?

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 10000,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.md"],
      "options": {
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "insertPragma": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use endOfLine but with no success....

Comment: Note that, although it is not required by the Markdown specification, it is considered best practise to add a blank line after a heading (e.g., https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#heading-best-practices).

Comment: See also for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401036/ which contains an example of the Stack Overflow server-side markdown parser rendering the wrong result if the blank line is not there. This means that Stack Overflow does not follow the official specification, which is a bug on their part, but it does happen and this will not be the only heavily used markdown parser that gets it wrong.